# Difference between struct.unpack() and int.from_bytes()?

Tags: python

Is there a difference between the two? When should I use one over the other? They do the same thing basically except struct.unpack() works for multiple byte sequences. Should I still use struct.unpack() if I only need to convert one byte sequence, or should I use int.from_bytes()? I'm just curious to know.

Comment: well, for starters, `int.from_bytes` will only ever return a single `int` object

Comment: @BoarGules Completely wrong! 1. A `bytes` is not a Python list as lists are mutable and `bytes` objects are not. 2. "Built-in objects that support the buffer protocol include bytes and bytearray." (cited from Built-in Types, Sect. "Binary Sequence Types — bytes, bytearray, memoryview"). 3. `struct.pack` returns a `bytes` object, and "the bytes of a packed struct correspond exactly to the layout in memory of the corresponding C struct." (cited from struct — Interpret bytes as packed binary data).

Answer (score 3):

Well, for starters, `int.from_bytes` will only ever return a single `int` object, so if you want to create anything other than an `int`, you can't use `int.from_bytes`.

Second, `struct.unpack` only supports fixed-length numeric C types. `int.from_bytes` supports arbitrarily-sized integers (which `int` objects are):

```
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xff'*8, 'little')
18446744073709551615
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xff'*10, 'little')
1208925819614629174706175
>>> int.from_bytes(b'\xff'*100, 'little')
6668014432879854274079851790721257797144758322315908160396257811764037237817632071521432200871554290742929910593433240445888801654119365080363356052330830046095157579514014558463078285911814024728965016135886601981690748037476461291163877375
```

If you only ever want a single integer, I would probably just use `int.from_bytes`. The general purpose of the `struct` module is to parse C structs into Python objects.